# string comparison using != is returning true even both strings are the same

Tags: c#, .net, string, comparison

I have the following code inside my asp.net application:

```
if (i["ProjectDescription"] != null && properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectDescription"] != null && (Regex.Replace(i["ProjectDescription"].ToString(), "<.*?>", String.Empty) != Regex.Replace(properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectDescription"].ToString(), "<.*?>", String.Empty)))
 {
    var g = Regex.Replace(i["ProjectDescription"].ToString(), "<.*?>", String.Empty);
    var gg = Regex.Replace(properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectDescription"].ToString(), "<.*?>", String.Empty);
}
```

now the `properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectDescription"]` =

```
<div class=\"ExternalClassB4424BCE886A43C980835358CB67D0E8\"><p>This project will be to update Win Server 2008 or older server OS to Win Server 2016.q​123​​<br><br></p><p>It will exclude Win Server 2012.&#160;</p><p>Check attached spreadsheet in draft for list of servers and check the POF&#160;</p><p>Licenses&#58;</p><p>Tere will&#160; be a total of 9 Server VMs upgraded on-premises that require Win Server Licenses.&#160;<br></p><p>There are also 2 existing VMs running on Win Server 2012.<br></p><p>This will require&#160;​6 x (16 cores licenses x 3 hosts) ---&gt; Total 18 x 16 cores Win Standard License​<br>already have 5 x 16 cores Win Standard licenses</p><p>We will need to quote and order for additional 13​ x&#160; Win Server Standard16 cores licenses​<br></p><p>The VM's running on Cloud will be licensed through monthly hosting costs</p><p><strong>Cost Summary&#58;​</strong><br>Licenses - £12,612.60<br>Engineer Resources - £7,880.00<br></p></div>
```

the `i["ProjectDescription"]`=

```
<div class=\"ExternalClassB4424BCE886A43C980835358CB67D0E8\"><p>This project will be to update Win Server 2008 or older server OS to Win Server 2016.q​123<br><br></p><p>It will exclude Win Server 2012.&#160;</p><p>Check attached spreadsheet in draft for list of servers and check the POF&#160;</p><p>Licenses&#58;</p><p>Tere will&#160; be a total of 9 Server VMs upgraded on-premises that require Win Server Licenses.&#160;<br></p><p>There are also 2 existing VMs running on Win Server 2012.<br></p><p>This will require&#160;​6 x (16 cores licenses x 3 hosts) ---&gt; Total 18 x 16 cores Win Standard License​<br>already have 5 x 16 cores Win Standard licenses</p><p>We will need to quote and order for additional 13​ x&#160; Win Server Standard16 cores licenses​<br></p><p>The VM's running on Cloud will be licensed through monthly hosting costs</p><p><strong>Cost Summary&#58;​</strong><br>Licenses - £12,612.60<br>Engineer Resources - £7,880.00<br></p></div>
```

also the result for the `Regex` will retrun the following:-

```
This project will be to update Win Server 2008 or older server OS to Win Server 2016.q​123It will exclude Win Server 2012.&#160;Check attached spreadsheet in draft for list of servers and check the POF&#160;Licenses&#58;Tere will&#160; be a total of 9 Server VMs upgraded on-premises that require Win Server Licenses.&#160;There are also 2 existing VMs running on Win Server 2012.This will require&#160;​6 x (16 cores licenses x 3 hosts) ---&gt; Total 18 x 16 cores Win Standard License​ already have 5 x 16 cores Win Standard licensesWe will need to quote and order for additional 13​ x&#160; Win Server Standard16 cores licenses​The VM's running on Cloud will be licensed through monthly hosting costsCost Summary&#58;​Licenses - £12,612.60Engineer Resources - £7,880.00
```

but the above string comparison will return true, althought the 2 string are the same. so can anyone advice?

Comment: you can use !String.IsNullOrEmpty("yourString")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The strings aren't the same. The word `----` is missing in the first string but present in the second (I removed the word as requested by OP as it was an actual username).

`properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectDescription"]`:

> `...Total 18 x 16 cores Win Standard License​<br>already have 5 x 16 cores Win Standard licenses</p>...`

`i["ProjectDescription"]`:

> `...Total 18 x 16 cores Win Standard License​<br>`**`----`**`already have 5 x 16 cores Win Standard licenses</p>...`

And as MindSwipe said in a comment, there are differences around `2016.q123<br><br></p><p>It`, as there seem to be non printing characters there.

Comment: Plus "2016.q123<br><br></p><p>It" is also different, there are non printing characters there [proof](https://www.diffchecker.com/3xykMIXx) ([smaller proof](https://www.diffchecker.com/x7mRcFjx))

Comment: @Ismael Padilla sorry i forgot to remove the text , since it contain a username.. i updated my question.. this word is already in the 2 text

Comment: Thank you @MindSwipe, I've edited my answer. test your problem is then probably related to the non printing chars

Comment: @IsmaelPadilla do you mind removing the word "Qu***a" as it is a real user name. thanks. i enter it by mistake

Comment: @testtest then the difference is with the "2016.q123<br><br></p><p>It" part, there appear to be some non printing characters there. Plus, anyone can go look at the revision history of this SO post and see everything, even deleted content from a post. IsmaelPadilla: No Problem, here to help

Comment: @MindSwipe did not get your point about `2016.q123<br><br></p><p>It`??

Comment: @testtest Take a look at [this](https://www.diffchecker.com/dJBGJlQY) diff, as you can see there are [non printing characters ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) in the "2016.q..." part that are causing the difference

Comment: @MindSwipe ok i got your point, so how i can exclude this from the comparison? as i did for the html tags?